# Append more data to form before submit?

Tags: jquery, forms, blob, form-submit, multipartform-data

I can't figure out why this isn't working?

```
var $formElement = $("#upload-form");
var formData = new FormData($formElement);
formData.append("file", blob_output, "timelapse.webm");
formData.append('token', token);

$formElement.submit();
```

I want to append the file `timelapse.webm` and also the `token` data when I submit `$("#upload-form")`. It doesn't seem to be working.

The inspector shows this is empty:

[image: This is the request payload.]

Related information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Retrieving_a_FormData_object_from_an.C2.A0HTML.C2.A0form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the FormData, not submit the HTML form. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: submitUrl,
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Not forgetting `var formData = new FormData($("#upload-form")[0]);`. That `[0]` is important.